# Following Mike Dane's Xamarin Basics Tutorial but Shown a Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It's a cross-mobile pprogram, no Windows work.
Here's the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlannerApp"
             x:Class="PlannerApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:AssignmentViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry 
                x:Name="InputField"
                Text="{Binding NewAssignmentInputValue}"
                Placeholder="Assignment Name"
                ReturnCommand="{Binding AddAssignmentCommand}"
            />

            <ListView x:Name="AssignmentList" ItemsSource="{Binding Assignments}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <FlexLayout JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" AlignItems="Center" Padding="20,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding AssignmentName}" TextColor="Black"/>

                                <ImageButton 
                                    Source="delete.png" 
                                    Scale="0.5"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveAssignmentCommand, Source={x:Reference Assignments}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                />
                            </FlexLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and here's the viewModel for the Assignment class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace PlannerApp
{
    public class AssignmentViewModel
    {
        public static void Init() { }

        public ObservableCollection<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rendering reference for the View
        /// </summary>
        public AssignmentViewModel()
        {
            Assignments = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>();

            Assignments.Add(new Assignment("todo 1", false));
            Assignments.Add(new Assignment("todo 2", false));
            Assignments.Add(new Assignment("todo 3", false));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand AddAssignmentCommand => new Command(AddAssignment);
        public string NewAssignmentInputValue { get; set; }
        void AddAssignment()
        {
            Assignments.Add(new Assignment(NewAssignmentInputValue, false));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove the called assignment
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand RemoveAssignmentCommand => new Command(RemoveAssignment);
        void RemoveAssignment(object o)
        {
            Assignment assignmentBeingRemoved = o as Assignment;
            Assignments.Remove(assignmentBeingRemoved);
        }

    }
}
```

The Assignment model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace PlannerApp
{
    public class Assignment
    {
        public static void Init() { }

        public string AssignmentName { get; set; }
        public bool Complete { get; set; }

        public Assignment(string AssignmentName, bool Complete)
        {
            this.AssignmentName = AssignmentName;
            this.Complete = Complete;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 30:37. Can not find the object referenced by Assignments'

When I remove the Command and CommandParameters from the ImageButton it runs and renders just fine but as soon as I bind it the program runs but drops the above error.

Comment: Your post doesn’t contain any information about the actual error.  Why are you sure it’s related to the ImageButton?

Comment: There is no element named Assignments in your XAML

Answer (score 2):

`x:Reference Assignments` is not possible, because `Assignments` is not a UI element. PIcture UI elements as a tree starting at top of XAML. `x:Reference` must refer to some xaml element higher in the tree. Cannot refer to a viewmodel property.

Maybe should be `x:Reference AssignmentList`:

```xml
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveAssignmentCommand, Source={x:Reference AssignmentList}}"
```

Comment: Wait what?! It worked! Thanks so much! But why? I assumed that it was supposed to be a reference to the Collection called Assignments?

Comment: x:reference is basically a reference to a UI element in your XAML

Comment: That makes so much sense. Again thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Would you please mark this reply as answered so that others with similar questions will see it? Thanks.